# Sublime text, auto suggestions not showing from a vcpkg instal folder

Tags: autosuggest, sublimetext4

I have no idea how to even aproach this, im new to sublime text and i am able to build a file when including cpp packages, but when writing the code, it does'nt suggest the sqlite3 lib. I am on a raspberry pi with ubuntu setup. No issues with vcpkg nor building and compiling.

Ps: thanks in advance!